# How can I link elements to the show page with join in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I join the elements of an array as follows

```
(u.roles.collect {|role| link_to role.name, role}).join(", ")
```

then Rails will autoescape the text so I get

```
&lt;a href=&quot;/roles/3&quot;&gt;Role 1&lt;/a&gt;, 
&lt;a href=&quot;/roles/4&quot;&gt;Role 2&lt;/a&gt;
```

instead of the expected

```
<a href="/roles/3">Role 1</a>, <a href="/roles/4">Role 2</a>
```

How can I avoid autoescaping?

Comment: I don't see what's being escaped.

Comment: Sorry. I have clarified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the strings html safe:

```
(u.roles.collect {|role| link_to role.name, role}).join(", ").html_safe
```

This should work in Rails 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Rails are you using? Try 'raw', this should solve your problem
raw (u.roles.collect {|role| link_to role.name, role}).join(", ")